# Trouble with a multiple condition when statement in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

In Finland, like in many countries, we have name days for different names.

I'm trying to write an Ubersicht app to display the day of the year, and the name of that day.

I've brought in the Day of the Year (`%j`) and Year (`%Y`), split them so I can manipulate them, and have found [a way](https://www.w3resource.com/coffeescript-exercises/coffeescript-exercise-3.php) to find a leap year in CoffeeScript.

However, because leap years have an extra day, the 29th Feb is not a name day (along with 1st Jan and 25th Dec), so I want to display "No names today!" on those days, both when it is, and isn't, a leap year.

```
command: "date +%j,%Y"  

update: (output) ->
  dateString = output.split(',')

  yearday = parseInt(dateString[0])
  year = dateString[1]

  leapyear = (year % 400 == 0) or (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)


  # The Switch statement
  yearday = switch
      when (leapyear and yearday is [1, 60, 360]) then "No names today!"
      else 
        when yearday is 2 then " Aapeli "
        when yearday is 3 then " Elmer, Elmo "
        when yearday is 4 then " Ruut "

        ... and so on
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting an `ParseError: 'unexpected when'`.

I'm pretty new to building widgets (I have an idea how I would do this in Python), and I'm having some difficulty with my switch statement.

I have also tried bringing in the month day (`%d`) and month number (`%e`), but I ran into similar issues there (multiple when conditions e.g. when month = 3 and day = 5 (for 5th May) not working).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  As I said, I'm new to CoffeeScript, so explanations would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: `ParserError` means you're writing something it can't understand, i.e. syntax is wrong. It also tells you on which line it encountered the problem (and stops, so until you fix the first error, you don't know if there are any more.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reread [`switch` syntax](https://coffeescript.org/#switch)

```coffee
yearday = switch leapyear
  when 2 then 'Aapeli'
  when 3
    if additional_conditionals then A else B
  when 4 then 'Ruut'
  else 'No names today!'
  # else is default, you can't nest additional when statements here
```

However, the simpler solution would be to use an array instead.
(This is not quite about Coffeescript but applies to thinking about programming in general.)

```coffee
dayNames = ['', '', 'Aapeli', 'Elmer, Elmo', 'Ruut']
dayName = (day) => switch day
  when 0 then 'fails, no 0th day' # optional
  when 1, 60, 360 then 'No names today!'
  else "Name of day #{day} is #{dayNames[day]}."

# Additionally, don't prewrite the spaces.
# Use string manipulation like above instead
# (note the difference between single and double quotes)

console.log dayName 4
# 'Name of day 4 is Ruut.'
console.log dayName 60
# 'No names today!'
```

(Btw please remove extra info about Finland days, it's just irrelevant..)

Cheers :)